# Is $\mathbb{C}^m\times\mathbb{C}^n=\mathbb{C}^{m+n}$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

In real analysis we have
$\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} = \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, e.g.
$$
\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^2=\big \{
(x,y): x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in\mathbb{R}
\big\}
$$

Is this also true for complex numbers, i.e. $\mathbb{C}^m\times\mathbb{C}^n=\mathbb{C}^{m+n}$?

Comment: Yes. I've never known it to be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 7):

As in, the Cartesian product of sets? In order to answer that you have to recall the recursive definition:

$$X^1:= X$$
$$X^n:=X\times X^{n-1}$$

(there are alternative yet equivalent ways to define $X^n$) Now since we have the natural bijection

$$A\times (B\times C)\to (A\times B)\times C$$
$$(a, (b,c))\mapsto ((a,b),c)$$

it follows that the Cartesian product is "associative". With that property you can easily prove that

$$X^{n+m}\simeq X^{n}\times X^{m}$$

where $\simeq$ stands for "is equinumerous to". You do that by simply "rearranging brackets" (composing multiple natural bijections defined above) on the right side to match $X\times (X\times (X\times\cdots X)\cdots )$ pattern.

This bijection is good. As in really good. So good that in almost every scenario you encounter it will also preserve additional structures, e.g. if $X$ is a group then $\simeq$ is an isomorphism of groups. If $X$ is a topological space then $\simeq$ is a homeomorphism, etc. It is so good that mathematicians simply say that

$$X^{n+m}=X^n\times X^m$$

even though this is formally incorrect.

All in all, yes $\mathbb{C}^{n+m}=\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^m$.

Answer (score 6):

Formally, the answer is negative: $\mathbb{C}^m\times\mathbb{C}^n$ is a set of ordered pairs, whereas $\mathbb{C}^{m+n}$ is a set of $(m+n)$-plets; therefore, they cannot possibly be equal, unless $m=n=1$ (in which case, yes, they are equal).

However, there is a natural bijection $B\colon\mathbb{C}^m\times\mathbb{C}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{m+n}$, given by$$B\bigl((z_1,\ldots,z_m),(w_1,\ldots,w_m)\bigr)=(z_1,\ldots,z_n,w_1,\ldots,w_m),$$which allows us to identify these spaces.

Of course, there is nothing pecular about the complex numbers heere. The same identification can be done with any set $A$ instead of $\mathbb C$ (and, in particular, with $\mathbb R$).

Comment: And what does it mean to "identify" these spaces? (I think it just means "refer to them by the same name, even though they are different things, and hope that it's always clear from context which of the two distinct things we are referring to.)

Comment: @littleO Not quite. I could also identify $A^2\times A$ with $A^3$ through the map$$\bigl((a,b),c\bigr)\mapsto(a,c,b),$$ but that's not what I did. So, indeed I “refer to them by the same name, even though they are different things, and hope that it's always clear from context which of the two distinct things we are referring to”, but I *also* expect that the reader understands *in which way* I identify each element of one of the sets with an element of the other set.